# Append method for linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class _ListNode:

  def __init__(self, value, next_):

      self._data = value
      self._next = next_
      return


 class List:

      def __init__(self):

         self._front = None
         self._count = 0
         return

      def _linear_search(self,key):
           previous = None
           current = self._front
           index = 0

          while current is not None and key > current._data:
               previous = current
               current = current._next
               index += 1
          if current._data != key:
          previous = None
          current = None
          index = -1

         return previous, current, index



     def __contains__(self, key):

          _, _, i = self._linear_search(key)
          return i != -1

      def append(self, value):

           if self._front is None:
              self._front = _ListNode(value,None)
           else:
              self._front._next = _ListNode(value,None)
           self._count += 1

   l = List()
   lst = [1,2,3,4]
   i = 0
   n = len(lst)
   while i < n:
      l.append(lst[i])
      i += 1
   print("{}".format(l.__contains(3))
```

To explain more, I implement the linear search method and the contains method. The contains method check if the number is in the list or not (returns true or false). Now when I need to check that #3 in the list using contains method, the answer is false!! i cant know what's the problem

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that can actually be used to recreate the issue.

Comment: That didn't really help. Please read the linked page in the help center. People should be able to copy and paste the code from your question, run it, and see the same output you describe.

Comment: Your edit improved your code, but it's still missing the method that prints a `List`. Running that code, `print(l)` just outputs something like `<__main__.List instance at 0x283A148>`.

Comment: Your append method always adds only to `self._front._next` you need to instead find the last node and add to that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your append method does not walk down the list. It simply always appends to `self._front._next` if `self.front` is already present. Meaning the contents at the end of the append loop are the first thing you appended, the last thing you appended and nothing in between.

To correct it walk the list looking for a `_next` equal to `None` and append there.

```
def append(self, value):

    if self._front is None:
        self._front = _ListNode(value, None)
    else:
        n = self._front
        while n._next is not None:
            n = n._next
        n._next = _ListNode(value, None)

    self._count += 1
```

You could also define a `_str__` method to print the content of the `List`

e.g.

```
def __str__(self):
    res = []
    n = self._front
    while n is not None:
        res.append(str(n._data))
        n = n._next

    return ', '.join(res)
```

This is not a particularly efficient implementation as it builds an intermediate builtin `list` object.

You also don't need those bare `return` statements in your methods. You can remove those.

Comment: Thanks for helping :D

Comment: great. You can accept and upvote if it was a useful answer. I see you edited your question, please let me know if it renders this answer in any way wrong.

Comment: when i remove  #3 from the list (for example), then append it another time and check if its in the list, the answer is false!!

Comment: ok that will be because of either your remove function or your linear search function. May I suggest asking a new question if you are stuck on this.

Comment: my remove function works, I used insert method instead of append, and everything is fine, but when I use the append method it works except when I remove the number and append it another time

Comment: best thing you can do is inspect the content of the list after each action, to see where it messes up. Like I said a new question is the way to go.